# How to write this if else block in ternary form

Tags: javascript

How can I write this as ternary form:

```
  if (localStorage.getItem("txt")) {
    newNote(localStorage.getItem("txt"), localStorage.getItem("name"));
  } else {
    newNote();
  }
```

This seems not working:

```
newNote(localStorage.getItem("txt") ? localStorage.getItem("txt"), localStorage.getItem("name") ? newNote();
```

Comment: Why ? look at the answers, they're much less clear than the `if` form. If I had to drive a project with the ternary form used here, I'd probably make it written in the first way...

Comment: So I will prefer the if-else statement instead of ternary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer to the question:

```
localStorage.getItem("txt")
  ? newNote(localStorage.getItem("txt"), localStorage.getItem("name"))
  : newNote();
```

But honestly I don't see why it should be done in this way, it's less readable. I would just make the `newNote` function in a way where, if the arguments given are `null`, it's like a `newNote()` without arguments. In that case, you can just call:

```
newNote(localStorage.getItem("txt"), localStorage.getItem("name"))
```

Without any `if` in the main code, and in the `newNote` function:

```
function newNote(text, name) {
    if (text === null) {
        // alias to `newNote()`
    } else {
        // do whatever with `text` and `name`
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
var note = localStorage.getItem("txt")?newNote(localStorage.getItem("txt"), localStorage.getItem("name")):newNote();
```

The syntax is `boolean?expr1:expr2;`

But what i would suggest is using something like this:

```
var note=getNode(localStorage.getItem("txt"),localStorage.getItem("name"));
...
function getNode(txt,name){
  return txt.length>0?newNote(txt,name):newNode();
}
```

Comment: @Jonathan yeap, thats true

Answer (score 1):

```
localStorage.getItem("txt") ? newNote(localStorage.getItem("txt"), localStorage.getItem("name")) : newNote();
```

Comment: `localStorage.getItem("txt"), localStorage.getItem("name") ` should be the argument if `(localStorage.getItem("txt")) ` exists.

Comment: Yep, i put these two as parameters for `newNote()` if `localStorage.getItem("txt")` returns true

Answer (score 1):

Why would you do this in such an ugly way?

Just check in your `newNote` body if the parameters are set

```
function newNote(a, b) {
  a = a || 'default';
  b = b || 'default';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  var a= localStorage.getItem("txt")?newNote(localStorage.getItem("txt"),localStorage.getItem("name"):newNote();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need conditional operator. Try this:

```
var txt = localStorage.getItem("txt");
newNote(txt, txt && localStorage.getItem("name"));
```

if `txt` is `undefined`, then `newNote` will be invoked without any arguments, if it is: with `txt` and `name`.

Answer (score 0):

I like the way @ZER0 suggests but I would do this way.

just to make it simple to read I will assign `localStorage.getItem("txt")` and  `localStorage.getItem("name")` to a variable:

```
var a = localStorage.getItem("txt");
var b = localStorage.getItem("name");

test(a ? [a, b] : []);

function test(options){
    if(options.length > 0){
        alert("a");
    }else{
        alert("ab");
    }
}
```